Calculating total length of all pedestrian walkways from OpenStreetMaps
I am new to OSM and am tryng to leverage it to calculate the total length of pedestrian walkways (i.e., footways and sidewalks) within individual cities. I am using OSM wiki to determine which keys I should be using to account for all type of paths (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway). My focus is on footways and sidewalks.
The code below show the types of paths I am summing to get the total length of all pedestrians paths in the city. However, I am not sure if I am covering all my bases or double counting certain paths. Will the below list of keys get me the total sidewalk length across a city, or should I add/remove any? For context, I'm confident that my code returns path length - my question is about making sure that I am accounting for all the types of pedestrian paths.
    way["footway"=sidewalk](area.a);
    way["sidewalk"=both](area.a);
    way["sidewalk"=left](area.a);
    way["sidewalk"=right](area.a);
    way["footway"=crossing](area.a);
    way["footway"=traffic_island](area.a);
    way["footway"=alley](area.a);
    way["footway"=residential](area.a);
    way["highway"=footway](area.a);
    way["highway"=pedestrian](area.a);

As an example: sidewalks can take a value of left, right, both, lane, sepearte, yes, or no according to OSM wiki. I'm not sure which I should and should not be including in my total sum (so far I only included right, left, and both). Similar questipons apply for footways.
Thanks in advance.

In addition to the obvious highway=footway and highway=pedestrian tags, you should also consider implicitly mapped sidewalks and highway types used for shared or mixed-use paths.
Implicitly mapped sidewalks can be present as sidewalk= tags on the way representing the road the sidewalk belongs to. You're already checking for some of these. However, you should make sure to count sidewalk=both twice (as this represents a sidewalk on each side of the road), and you should also consider sidewalk=yes. (Unfortunately, you cannot know for sure if there is one or two sidewalks in the latter case.)
Shared or mixed-use paths can be tagged as highway=path, highway=cycleway or highway=bridleway. The "path" value is even a quite common alternative to highway=footway for pedestian-only paths. You need to look at access tags such as foot=yes and foot=designated to know whether pedestrians are allowed to use these. If no such tags are present, you may have to rely on (potentially country-specific) default assumptions. You can also look at the segregated=* key if you're interested in that distinction.
Looking at the various footway=* tags which you currently include in your query could be useful if you want to distinguish sidewalks from other types of footways, or have a special treatment for crossings. Otherwise, it is likely not necessary to include them, as they're generally used in addition to a primary tag such as highway=footway or highway=path. However, as long as you're not counting the ways twice, including these tag shouldn't hurt.
Other caveats:

Coverage of this data in OSM will only approach completeness in a minority of the world's cities. If you compare cities according to this metric, you may be comparing OSM mapper activity rather than, or in addition to, pedestrian network length.
Polygon features, such as plazas, do not have an obvious "length". They are mapped as areas – either closed ways additionally tagged with area=yes or multipolygon relations. Sometimes, mappers additionally draw linear connections across plazas as a workaround for simple routing software that cannot handle polygons. Therefore, a naive implementation is likely to end up either double-counting (both the outline and the ways across the plaza), miscounting (counting outline length instead of a more sensible "length" of the plaza) or missing such features.
Depending on local mapping practices, there may be some "by-catch" such as indoor corridors or ways in underground train stations.

